# In Firebase, can I get signal from .observeSingleEventOfType() that it finished executing its code block?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please take a look at the following code. varable `v` gets a sort of `String` from Firebase db, then it gets printed.

```
var v = "no"
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

ref.child("db").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
    v = snapshot.value!["blah"] as! String//assume it gets "ok"
    print("This one shouldn't come first")
})                

print("v is \(v)!!")
```

The actual codes in `.observeSingleEventOfType()` are more complicated but this one is okay.

In that method, variable `v` gets a `String`. But the print statement would not print `"ok"` but `"no"`, for the method is asynchronous.

What I want to do is get a signal or something like that from `.observeSingleEventOfType()` that it finished executing all code lines, then execute the `print()` method.

Is it possible to do what I want? Or can I pause all the codes until that code block finishes?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Dravidian The code is supposed to get an array of `[String : String]` and assign to the same type of variable declared in the class. Calling the data from the designated variable does not work properly right after execution of `.observeSingleEventOfType()` method.

Comment: Ofcource it wont , its asynchronous. you need to access the variable inside the completionBlock.Also look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

`completionBlocks:` in itself are kind of a signal that your method or function has completed its function something like this

```
func printData(){

         retrieveData{(retrievedBlah) in 
                print(retrievedBlah) //"Ok"
              }
         } 



func retrieveData(completionBlock : ((blah : String!) -> Void)){

    ref.child("db").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
              v = snapshot.value!["blah"] as! String//assume it gets "ok"
              completionBlock(blah : v)  
              print("This one shouldn't come first")
          }) 

       }
```

But if you still want to check wether or not the value that you tried store in DB has been saved or not, Listen to that node with an eventType according to :-

- case ChildAdded // 0, fired when a new child node is added to a location
- case ChildRemoved // 1, fired when a child node is removed from a location
- case ChildChanged // 2, fired when a child node at a location changes
- case ChildMoved // 3, fired when a child node moves relative to the other child nodes at a location
- case Value // 4, fired when any data changes at a location and, recursively, any children

And then cross check if it stored or not...

Comment: The answer will not work. observeSingleEventOfType is expecting a collection of values. The answered completionBlock block will work after the first value is retrieved. I think, OP is asking about the completion of entire data fetch.

Comment: What do you mean by *completion of entire data fetch?* That the JSON is being DOWNLOADED progressively and at the first instance of the retrieval, this completionBlock  will be triggered but the signal to recieve is when the entire JSON has been downloaded. Is that it?

Comment: what will happen while execute a query that retrieve 10 rows? example FIRDatabaseQuery *recentPostsQuery = [[[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"StockMaster"] queryLimitedToLast:10];
 
[recentPostsQuery observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSLog(@"@%@", snapshot.value);
    }];

Comment: the NSLog(@"@%@", snapshot.value); will execute 10 times in this. How do you find the completion? it may execute only five times if the database contains only 5 rows.

Comment: FIRDataSnapshot receiving block **`withBlock:`** is in itself a completion block. It is only called when the entire snapshot(i.e Requested Database Entries) is retrieved, not at the single retrieval. in your doubt, `queryLimitedToLast:10]`, will not fire the completionBlock each and every time an element is retrieved. It will first retrieve the entire 10 rows and then the completionBlock will be fired. To iterate through those you would need to loop over the retrieved Data. Please check your theories before you post. :)Happy Coding

Comment: "It will first retrieve the entire 10 rows and then the completionBlock will be fired." - it will not. This will happen sequentially and you don't have the completionBlock here to fire :)

Comment: Again just check your theory before you start posting comments and downvoting answers. Try printing the snap in your project and use breakpoints...:)